# Using inner join to delete a row from Table A or Table B

Tags: mysql, join, union, sql-delete

I am writing queries for my rest api and this query should delete a row in a table depending whether a name is selected from Table A or Table B. So if a user inputs a name from table A then the whole row in which the name is should be deleted. The same should be for table B

This is my query

```
'DELETE FROM Table_A, Table_B USING Table_A INNER JOIN Table_B  WHERE name = ?'
```

I have checked online but I didn't find a similar query where a column = ?

Could someone help me out ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to 'hard-delete' data?

Comment: @Strawberry is it bad practice? and are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Well once data has gone, there's no getting it back (well, there's the backup); so you placing a lot of faith in the user not to mess things up.

Comment: unless I copy the values of the two tables into another table , but that would be a different question and I would also have to do it with join which I couldn't figure out

Comment: Does the values need to exist in both tables? If not, why not just two sequential `DELETE`s?

Comment: @stickybit  it's pretty funny. When I tried before my server crashed now I did two separate deletes and everything works fine